# Write files when looping line by line instead of overwriting

Tags: python, datetime, time, file-io

I'm trying to write something in a file every second with the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time

def test():
    f = open(r"C:\logs.txt","w")
    time = datetime.now()
    f.write("test " + str(time))
    f.write("\n")

schedule.every().second.do(test)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

But when I'm looking at the logs.txt file, the result is this :

```
test 2020-08-08 21:10:52.605432
```

instead of (what I would like to do):

```
test 2020-08-08 21:10:52.605432
test 2020-08-08 21:10:53.605432
test 2020-08-08 21:10:54.605432
...
```

The code seems to overwrite the first line instead of writing line by line every time there is a new second.
Could you help me ?
Thanks

Updated code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time

def test():
    f = open(r"C:\logs.txt","a")
    time = datetime.now()
    f.write("test " + str(time))
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()
    

while True:

    schedule.every().second.do(test) 
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: use `f = open(r"C:\logs.txt","a")` for appending

Comment: it looks like you should add for loop in the code, do you know how to loop through the lines of your file?

Comment: nvm, the guys above just gave a better idea

Comment: @Occhima The OP is writing to, not reading from, a file.

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your file in appending mode to avoid overwriting: `open(r"C:\logs.txt","a")`. Additionally, I suggest using a `with` statement to close the file automatically after you have finished writing.

Example Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time

def test():
    with open(r"C:\logs.txt","a") as f:
        time = datetime.now()
        f.write("test " + str(time))
        f.write("\n")

schedule.every().second.do(test)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `append` is not a file method?

Comment: Thanks, I tried putting append instead and I also tried a with statement, but it continues to write on the same line (resulting a single line in log.txt) instead of writing line by line each second :/

Comment: I just found the answer, I had to put schedule.every().second.do(test) in the while loop, not before! I'm also using "a" instead of "w".
Strangely, it writes multiple times per second not as one time per second as I would like

Comment: Yes, that is because you are rescheduling the function every second.

Comment: @SumitYadav `writeFile` is also not a file method?

Comment: @SumitYadav that is what my answer says?